# how can we set checked a checkbox in a datagridview from a database in c#?

Tags: c#-3.0

i want to display a table from database, there is a column in datagridview, it is to be checked or not depends on the column in the database , how can? pls give an example ? Thanks a lot........

Answer (score 0):

Try this... loop through each row and check the value and set the checked value accordingly...

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if row.Cells[2].Value == "My Test Value" 
        {
             row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value = true;
        }
    }
```